# How To Fix "Expected scheme-specific part at index 10: classpath: " Error While Running A Feature File In Cucumber-Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I Am Trying To Run My Feature File. Run As Cucumber Feature In Eclipse. But I Am Getting Error.

When I Am Trying To Run The Runner Class (With Cucumber JVM + JUnit). It Is Running Fine.
Note :- Cucumber-Junit, Cucumber-java Jars Are Of Version 4.2.3. JUnit 4.12.

```
@Smoke
Feature: Google homepage Functionality.

Scenario: Google homepage.
Given I open a browser
When  I navigate to url
Then  Homepage should open
And   Search box should be present
But   No search result.



Runner Class :-
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "./src/test/resources/GoogleSearch.feature",
    glue = "Impl",
    plugin = { "pretty",
               "html:target/cucumber-htmlreport.html", 
               "json:target/cucmber-report.json" },
    tags= {"@Learn"}
    )
public class GoogleRunner {

}


 On Running feature file
 Error :-
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 
 scheme-specific part at index 10: classpath:
 at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
 at 
io.cucumber.core.model.GluePath.parseAssumeClasspathScheme(GluePath.java:54)
 at io.cucumber.core.model.GluePath.parse(GluePath.java:34)
 at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:160)
 at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:107)
 at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:100)
 at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:96)
 at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:131)
 at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:127)
 at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:22)
 at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
 Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at 
 index 10: classpath:
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3057)
 at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
 at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
 ... 10 more
```

Code Here : https://github.com/kwishna/Cucumber_1

Comment: Can u remove the initial "./" from the features path value and try.

Comment: Runner class is working fine. The error is coming only when I am running the feature file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also getting this issue, after using Cucumber Java/Junit 4.2.2 it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. Is it A Bug In Cucumber 4.2.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You must download the version of Cucumber Java / Junit 4.2.0 and check the version of java that is managed in the IDE.